# how do i multiply two cells by their names?

Tags: excel, vba

if one cell is called ALEX and the other is called ALEXALEX (instead of A1 and A2)., how do i multiply them such that i just enter a formula like C1 = AlEX * ALEXALEX instead of A1*A2?

Comment: The answer is in the question... You use `=ALEX*ALEXALEX` in your formula. Or is there something I don't understand?

Comment: @Romain Muller: Agreed. Should turn that on a answer...

Comment: You can also see all of these "named" cells if you go to the name manager. (its under the formulas ribbon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C1 typing = ALEX * ALEXALEX works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

That's actually the way you do it.

```
= ALEX * ALEXALEX
```

Am I missing something?